# Why the redundant adding and subtracting inside space commands?

Tags: spacing

Why do some commands like

`\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{5.5mm plus 1mm minus .2mm}{4.3mm plus .2mm}`

have this strange adding and subtracting for length. I.e. why not write `6.3mm` instead of 5.5+1-.2?

The prototype for this command is
`\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}`

So the numbers clearly represent spaces.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Those spaces are *stretchy*. They allow TeX to adjust the spacing as required to optimise the output according to its algorithm. This is the stretchiness which enables the algorithm to figure out (in many cases) good page breaks etc.

Comment: The difference between rigid (static) and stretchable lengths.

Comment: It's related for sure but the answer to my question is: "it is glue stretching" whereas the other asks directly about glue stretching. So my question will help another newbie who is confused by the adding and subtracting inside space commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
5.5mm plus 1mm minus .2mm
```

does not mean  `6.3mm` it means a length of natural size `5.5mm` that can stretch a further `1mm` or shrink by `.2mm` to help fit surrounding material into a predefined space (typically here the page height. This is called `glue` in the TeXBook or a Rubber Length in the LaTeX book.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much! So ignorant on my part and Tex never ceases to amaze me with all the things I don't know! Again, thank you very much!